# How can I delete records in Entity Framework using ExecuteSqlCommand?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOption))
{
    foreach (ManufacturecodeEntity mcodeEntity in ManufacturecodeEntities)
    {
         ManufacturecodeEntity pcodeEntity = mcodeEntity.Parent;
         pcodeEntity.IsCurrent = true;

         UnitOfWork.ManufacturecodeRepository.Update(pcodeEntity);
    }

    UnitOfWork.DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from manufacturecodes where detailstate_id=" + Id.ToString());
    UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

But when I run to method `ExecuteSqlCommand`, my application stops, then throws timeout exception.

I use `ExecuteSqlCommand` to delete records because records is more than 1500, if I use Entity Framework `Delete` and `SaveChanges` method, it will take 60s, I can't accept the result.

So I try the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method to improve the performance. Now it seems there is something wrong.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SqlParameters` in the `ExecuteSqlCommand` as:

```
UnitOfWork.DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from manufacturecodes where detailstate_id=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", id);
```

Comment: same result, time out exception

Answer (score 0):

I think I know correct way. I should use DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction instead of TransactionScope